# Raphael.js gradient in stroke

Tags: raphael

I made a customAttribute to draw a line connecting 2 points in a circle (see image on http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3319121/problem.png).

```
r.customAttributes.line = function (xloc, yloc, start, end, total, R) {
var alphas = 360 / total * start,
    alphae = 360 / total * end,
    as = (90 - alphas) * Math.PI / 180,
    ae = (90 - alphae) * Math.PI / 180,
    xs = xloc + R * Math.cos(as),
    ys = yloc - R * Math.sin(as),
    xe = xloc + R * Math.cos(ae),
    ye = yloc - R * Math.sin(ae),                       
    path;
path = [["M", xs, ys], ["Q", xloc, yloc, xe, ye]];
return {path: path};
};
```

Now I would like to add a gradient. So you would have a gradient from blue in point 1 ro red in point 2 to make the visual more smooth. This is possible for objects in Raphael.js, see for example http://raphaeljs.com/ichart.html and there are already answers on stackoverflow that answer how to (http://jsfiddle.net/L92Ch/538/), however to add gradients in strokes (no fill) seem to be impossible in raphael.js.

Does anybody has a solutions to this problem?

Comment: this seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771517/raphael-js-path-line-with-gradient/11053049#11053049

Answer (score 1):

As an update to rajkamal's answer you can apply the gradient to the stroke rather than filling it. http://jsfiddle.net/yVfhy/

Answer (score 0):

Gert,

The obvious choice, as Raphael can't do gradient strokes (as far as I know), is to fake it. I'd create a rect of the right dimensions and rotate, translate it into place.

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/5aKRU/) from the fiddle you mentioned above.

Obviously, you're restricted to straight lines, not curves.

Comment: Hmmm... on second reading, it's a curve you want, not a line. D'oh.

Answer (score 0):

if my understanding of your question is right- you are trying to create a gradient fill inside a closed path.

I have took some random paths and filled the gradient (from red to blue) which resembles the inner arch as in your image.

Code:http://jsfiddle.net/qp3xf/

thanks